# COPY FROM / INSERT Millions of Rows Into Same PostgreSQL table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with hundreds of millions of rows that I need to essentially create a "duplicate" of each existing row in, doubling its row count. I'm currently using an insert operation (and unlogging the table prior to inserting) which still takes a long while as one transaction. Looking for guidance on if there may be a more efficient way to execute the query below.

```
INSERT INTO costs(
    parent_record, is_deleted
    ) 
SELECT id, is_deleted 
FROM costs;
```

Comment: Making it unlogged as a temporary measure is generally counterproductive, as making it unlogged and making it logged again are **both** quite costly.  Dropping indexes would probably be more useful.

Comment: Use system tools to identify the bottleneck.  But adding hundreds of millions of rows is going to take a long time no matter what you do.